# Trouble understanding this small review

Tags: reading-comprehension

> 木造の建物**なのでしかないけれど**大変寒かったです。
>   またフロントの方は夜帰るので、**到着が遅れてしまい**、申し訳ないことをしました。
>   8時**で予約しました**が到着が8時40分頃になり、**電話を頂戴しました**。[from here](https://www.booking.com/reviews/jp/hotel/beach-side-inn-shirahama.ja.html)

1. What does なのでしかないけれど mean? I've searched but found nothing.
2. Who is the subject of 到着が遅れてしまい?
3. What does the particle で mean with the verb 予約しました?
4. 電話を頂戴しました means "received a call" but I don't understand how it fits the context?

I understand more or less each word separately but can't understand the global story from this text because of the omission of the subjects etc.

Please don't tell me that I haven't searched because it is not the case, I even have asked in some other places before posting here but nobody gave me an answer.

Comment: しかないけれど should be a typo of 「しか**た**ないけれど」

Comment: My guess though, the reviewer could be not a native speaker, I'm also having troubles to get the whole meaning. The translation is like, 
"It can't help though, it was cold inside because it's a wooden building. Also, I'm sorry that I arrived late, since the receptionist (usually) leave at night. I booked 8 p.m., and I arrived at 8:40 p.m., so I got a call." , just FYI.

Comment: ^ いえ。。日本語話者でしょうね。。。 「しかない」のタイポを除けば、全体は自然な日本語ですので・・

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I think it is a typo. It would be 木造の建物なのでしか**た**ないけれど.
2. The reviewer.
3. It has the same meaning as 8時に予約していた (I made a reservation for eight o'clock).
4. I think that the reviewer received a call from the hotel receptionist because the reviewer was late.